# Pelican site generator: themes do not have visible table borders?

Tags: html, css, pelican

I'm using Pelican 3.6.3 to generate a site. The source content is in Markdown, and contains a number of tables. I've tried generating output with four or five different Pelican themes, but the tables never have any visible borders. All the table content is arranged neatly in rows and columns, but there are no cell borders or outside borders.

Is there a specific reason for this? Am I intended to modify the CSS manually? It seems unlikely that all of the theme authors would make this same design decision.

Example of one of my tables:

```
| Measurement      | 2401     | 2701    |
|------------------|----------|---------|
| Total height     | 2 13/16" | 4 1/8"  |
| Diameter at base | 4"       | 4 9/16" |
```

Comment: That's most likely your browsers default styles. Chrome doesn't display table borders by default  anymore for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the HTML attribute `border` set? If so, it is most likely the decision of your browser how to render the table.

I checked a few themes myself (just by having a quick glance at the CSS code, no guarantee for correctness):

```
| Theme           | Border |
|=================|========|
| apricot         | No     |
| basic           |        |
| bluegrasshopper |        |
| blueidea        |        |
| blue-penguin    |        |
| bold            |        |
|-----------------|--------|
| backdrop        | Yes    |
| bootlex         |        |
```

I can imagine that depending on the contents, the justification and other formatting aspects make having borders on **all** tables inappropriate. Consequently, I can understand the design decision to, per default, disable table borders and let the user of the theme customize the behavior, if required.

On my website, I use tables for many different things. Often, especially when blocks like images or syntactically highlighted areas are included, borders would make the table look weird. As of this I second this design decision.

But still, what if one wants borders on **some** tables? Case-dependent styling using CSS is easy to achieve if special HTML classes can be specified in the article source file. Unfortunately, `python-markdown` (or `markdown` in general) does not support this kind of feature. At least, this is what a short Google research revealed. (Maybe there is a `python-markdown` extension I did not recognize?..)

Another way would be to use another markup language. `reStructuredText` is more complex but also much more extensible in comparison to markdown. The [table](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/directives.html#tables) directive natively supports the specification of HTML classes. I use `reStructuredText` myself and like the high amount of flexibility the markup language introduces.

You could also let `javascript` do the job and set HTML classes likewise styling depending on the table contents. However, I would not consider this a good solution as you create a dependency on javascript for the appearance of a static website.

I hope this helps you :)

**tl;dr**

- The specific reason is most likely to be more generally applicable as a theme.
- Yes, you are invited to introduce the desired customizations yourself in the CSS code or wherever it suits you best.